# Where to find appDependencies in Play 2.0 application? It's already been set? if not how should I set it

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I tried something like this in my `build.sbt`:

```
val main = play.Project("hello-play-java", "1.0-SNAPSHOT", Seq("com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "2.2.3")).settings(
    // Force compilation in java 1.7
     javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")
)
```

but the compilation get `'com.wordnik' %% 'swagger-play2-utils' % '2.2.3' not find` error, I just randomly put it since I don't know where to get it..

Answer (score 0):

What version of Play 2 are you using? You mention `build.sbt` which would suggest Play 2.2+, however you code snippet suggests Play 2.0.x - 2.1.x (upgrading legacy project)?

When you say "not find error", if you are referring to sbt not being able to resolve `'swagger-play2-utils' % '2.2.3'` then that is because the [latest Swagger dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wordnik/swagger-play2-utils_2.10) version available from Maven central is 1.3.6.

For reference, here is what your build configurations would look like for the relevant Play versions.

For Play 2.2+:

build.sbt

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := "hello-play-java"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "1.3.6"
)

javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7")

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

For Play 2.0.x - 2.1.x:

Build.scala

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "hello-play-java"

  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore,
    ...
    "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "1.3.6"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7"),
    ...
}
```